# How to listen events from all azure subscription using Azure Event Grid?

Tags: publish-subscribe, azure-eventgrid

I have a list of azure subscriptions, where i would like to listen to the events (e.g. virtual machine created) from those azure subscriptions (i am not the owner) with Azure Event Grid.

Is that possible to do that? Is it possible to use a full access service principle to listen to those subscriptions events?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Event Grid is a **PUSH** eventing Pub/Sub model, where the interested events are distributed using the FAN-OUT and FAN-IN patterns.

In other words, there is no listener/receiver for waiting (**PULL/POLL**) on the interest event.

For your solution, you can use the **FAN-IN** pattern, where the multiple events are delivered to the same destination resource (subscriber), for instance, EventGridTrigger Function, etc.

The following screen snippet shows an example of the FAN-IN pattern:

[image]

Comment: sorry i think maybe i didn't ask the question clearly, what i mean is azure subscription, which one layer on top of azure resource group. I want to listen to events from those azure subscription which im not the owner

Comment: System topics can be created on the following Azure services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/system-topics Note, that the azure resource group is the highest level of the system topic creation, so when you subscribed on that topic, your endpoint will receive all events for that group.  In other words, you have to FAN-IN all delivery events from each interested resource group cross the Azure subscriptions (tenants).

Comment: thanks for answering, so do you mean, i have to install/create system topics on every resource group that i want to get events from? say, i have 100 resource groups, each of them need to have system topic created

Comment: Basically, the topic and event subscription must be in the same resource group, so to answer your comment's question, yes, you have to FAN-IN (system topic + event subscription) all 100 resource groups.